# Difference between graphql api and rest api

Tags: api, rest, graphql

Can anyone tell me the difference between the REST API and GRAPHQL API? I am new to this concept and am confused.

Comment: This is something that is written about a lot. Often (unfortunately) in favor of GraphQL. If you did some googling, and read some of the results... can you share what you are confused about?

Answer (score 0):

The main differences that graphql is famous for:

- -->There is single API call in Graphql, but in case of Rest you have to handle multiple Api calls
- -->It's based on schema and type where REST is based on endpoint
- -->GraphQL is a query language for APIs and a runtime for fulfilling those queries

Different languages support different ways to use Graphql feature, but the main thing is schema.graphqls (include query and type ),graphQLDataFetchers -to bind query (for each query), Graphql provider where binding will happen.